# Timer not firing (timeInterval always == 0.0)

Tags: swift, timer, swift3

I have created a `Timer` inside a singleton and I have been fighting with why the `Timer` is not firing. I have looked over posts on here but I have not found one that I believe directly answers my issue.

```
class ConnectionStateMonitor : NSObject {
    static let shared = ConnectionStateMonitor()

    var isConnected = false

    fileprivate let reachability = Reachability()!
    fileprivate var reconnectTimer: Timer?
    fileprivate var reconnectPollInterval = TimeInterval(10.0)

    func initialise() {
        reachability.stopNotifier()

        reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in

            if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {
                Log.debug(message: "Reachable via WiFi")
            } else {
                Log.debug(message: "Reachable via Cellular")
            }

            self.updateConnectionState(isConnected: true)
        }
        reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
            Log.debug(message: "Not reachable")

            self.updateConnectionState(isConnected: false)
        }

        do {
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            //print("Unable to start notifier")
        }
    }

    func updateConnectionState(isConnected: Bool) {
        let wasConnected = self.isConnected

        Log.debug(message: "Update connection state: \(isConnected)")

        synchronize(lockObj: self, closure: {
            self.isConnected = isConnected
        })

        self.updateReconnectTimer()
    }

    fileprivate func updateReconnectTimer() {
        // Suspend any pending call.
        self.reconnectTimer?.invalidate()

        if !self.isConnected {
            self.reconnectTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: self.reconnectPollInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(ConnectionStateMonitor.attemptReconnect), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            // Uncommenting below fires the timer.
            //self.reconnectTimer?.fire()


            print("attempting to reconnect in self.reconnectPollInterval = \(self.reconnectPollInterval) \(self.reconnectTimer?.timeInterval)s")
        }
        else {
            self.reconnectTimer = nil
        }
    }

    @objc func attemptReconnect() {
        print("attempting to reconnect")

        self.comms?.hello(completionHandler: { success, message in
            self.updateReconnectTimer()
        })
    }
}
```

The print statement inside updateReconnectTimer prints out:

**attempting to reconnect in self.reconnectPollInterval = 10.0 Optional(0.0)s**

I can't for the life of me work out why the timeInterval property of my `Timer` would be 0.0 when I explicitly set it to 10.0. Calling `fire` correctly calls my function so I know that it is hooked up correctly.

Also to confirm there are no subsequent calls to the updateReconnectTimer function that would interfere.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

EDIT:

I have added in more code to show the issue, it appears that by updating the `Timer` in the completion handlers from `Reachability` which will be a background thread seems to prevent the `Timer` from firing.

Comment: the interval is 0 because it does not repeat but the first launch will be delayed 10 and your code works fine for me i just tested it

Comment: @zombie thanks for the explanation on timeInterval. I am not sure I like that behaviour, in my mind I expect to see the interval set to what it was initialised with whether it repeats or not. That seems like a strange choice to me. Anyhow I do have other bits of code in this class so I will try and create a clean class like the above and check if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the bug appeared to be relating to the fact that I was updating the `reconnectTimer` field on different threads. Forcing it to be updated on the same thread each time corrected the issue.